# How can I create a button to add a POI layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, layers, markers

I am making a map of a city with openlayers. I have the shapefile data of the POI (hospital,bank,school etc.) I want to add the layers with buttons not in layerswitcher. Like [whereis.com](http://www.whereis.com/)'s  quick search buttons ... Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add some javascript to your button to toggle the visibility of the layers. e.g. In your setup

```
var yourLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...);
```

Then in your button click event you just need something like

```
yourLayer.setVisibility(true);
```

or

```
map.layers[0].setVisibility(true)
```